# Какой дистрибутив выбрать?

Tags: linux

Здравствуйте.

Я хочу ознакомится с Линукс, что и как это работает, помогите выбрать дистрибутив. Я начинающий веб-программист. Хочу поставить на ноутбук (очень слабый). Характеристика: Processor TM8000 995Мгц, 256mb RAM, 32mb VGA.

Буду благодарен за любые советы и ссылки.

Хотелось что нибудь с интерфейсом командной строки =)

Comment: Выбирайте уже ответ их тыщи

Answer (score 4):

На таком ноутбуке Ubuntu будет притормаживать. Я сам перепробовал различные дистрибутивы (начал с Ubuntu, затем Fedora, Arch Linux, Gentoo, сейчас Debian). Ubuntu стояла у меня около месяца, потом решил поэкспериментировать. Если кратко, то на такой ноутбук ставьте Debian (быстро, стабильно и надежно). Если хочется посмотреть на Linux изнутри, то [Arch Linux](http://archlinux.org.ru/) или [Gentoo](http://gentoo.ru/). Arch Linux - проще, чем Gentoo, плюс там хорошая wiki. Посмотреть изнутри можно на любой дистрибутив, но Gentoo и Arch Linux к этому предрасполагают. После всех экспериментов я остановился на [Debian](http://www.debian.org/). По моему мнению, ставьте Debian stable (в установке и первоначальной настройке не намного сложнее чем, Ubuntu). В сети много статей по установке и первоначальной конфигурации, например [эта.](http://mydebianblog.blogspot.com/2006/08/in-true-debian-way.html) А если вдруг все равно что-то не получается, задавайте вопрос на форуме. Здесь Вам всегда помогут.

Comment: Тоже использую Debian вот уже 3 года. Поставил когда, собрался с мыслями разрабатывать простейшую браузерную онлайн игру. Так что проблем с базовой настройкой всего, что нужно для веб программирования, возникнуть не должно: все ставиться из репозитория, за исключением разве что приличной ide. Лично я скачал сборку Eclipse php из сети и не жалуюсь.

Answer (score 3):

Xubuntu потребляет такое же количество ресурсов, как и ubuntu (парадокс, но это так). Для юзера отличие ubuntu от debian заключается лишь в том, что в ubuntu присутствует больше GUI утилит конфигурирования системы. Стоит ли тогда вообще ставить ubuntu без x-ов (x-window-system)? Проще поставить debian, один раз настроить и забыть. Еще один из минусов Ubuntu в том, что она постоянно обновляется, а это не всегда положительно сказывается на работе системы. С Ubuntu проще только сначала, а потом надоедает постоянно что-то исправлять после очередного обновления.

Comment: Вы хотите поставить Linux, чтобы в последующем разобраться, как работает сервер на основе Linux, как я понял. Тогда это еще один повод смотреть в сторону Debian (по моему и не только мнению среди Linux'ов он самый достойный для организации сервера). А после того посмотрите еще BSD системы, например FreeBSD (http://freebsd.org/ru). Так как они тоже нередко используются в качестве серверов (да и в качестве десктопа ее тоже можно поставить).

Answer (score 3):

Рекомендую [Puppy Linux](http://www.puppylinux.com/). Имеет достаточно малый размер (от 70 мегабайт) и скромные системные требования (процессор Pentium I, оперативная память — 32 мегабайта), включает себе все необходимые приложения. Данный дистрибутив характеризуется легкостью настройки и модификации.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте [Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.com).

Comment: Согласен с jmen, ubuntu пойдет для начинающих. Только при чем тут "сервер" в тегах?

Comment: @Alex Silaev Вы можете сразу менять метки вопроса, если считаете, что они выставлены неудачно.

Answer (score 2):

Для предварительного ознакомления порекомендовал бы пока использовать LiveCD.
В принципе, не имеет разницы, какой дистрибутив. У разных некоторые различия
в системах инсталляции пакетов и расположении конфигурационных файлов.
Тормозить, конечно же, будет, но не придется устанавливать на винт, потом
сносить и устанавливать другой дистрибутив.
На mirror.yandex.ru можно выбрать для начала хотя бы Knoppix, или какой
другой.
Машина, конечно, слабовата, но если в качестве GUI использовать xfce4, то
познакомиться можно.
Не советовал бы тренироваться на системах BSD (Open, Free, Net и т.д.).
Они пока достаточно сложны для начинающих как в установке, так и в настройке.

Comment: Добавляю к ответу: еще можно Live дистрибутив для флешки найти.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то человек просит тока: "Хотелось что нибудь с интерфейсом командной строки =)"
и так как слабенькая машина, я бы выбрал Gentoo. Хорошо собранное ядро будет работать даже на калькуляторе.

Answer (score 1):

С таким количеством оперативной памяти и слабым процессором стоит попробовать поставить дистрибутив с легкой средой рабочего стола (xfce4, awsome, wm, openbox). То есть, можно попробовать дистрибутив xubuntu или поставить какой-либо дистрибутив без среды рабочего стола и потом поставить на него одну из выше перечисленных.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSUSE.
В качестве оболочки в порядке понижения желательности (т.е. в порядке повышения ресурсоемкости): LXDE, xfce, Gnome, KDE.
Первые две возможно придется допиливать под свои нужды. Gnome - в базовой конфигурации медленный, но если отключить эффекты начинает работать весьма быстро.
Обратить внимание, что возможно при установке lxde/xfce придется доустанавливать часть пакетов (напр., network manager и nm-applet).
Если же ставить без X'ов работает вполне адекватно тоже :-) Тем более, что утилиты конфигурирования для текстового режима тоже есть.

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/). Для работы в отличие от Ubuntu требует всего 128 оперативы

Answer (score 1):

А я буду оригинальным: Mandriva.

LAMP ставится очень просто и работает стабильно, вырезав KDE на вашем ноуте будет летать. Установка проще простого.

Прекрасная поддержка на форуме, где советуют, что делать, а не куда идти.

Comment: Мандрива имеет преимущественно платные дистрибутивы.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, лучше все же будет Debian+openbox, по настройке openbox и всяких мелочей можно почитать [тут](http://www.crunchbang.ru/viewforum.php?id=12).

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тому, что командная строка нужна, это будет сервер или вроде того.
Могу посоветовать CentOS, Debian, FreeBSD (не линукс, но unix). Скорее всего, любая из этих операционных систем вам подойдет.

Answer (score 1):

arch, gentoo (но в gentoo тяжело разобраться)

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос скорее не в дистрибутиве, а в том что ставить-то для веб-программирования?
Если одну консоль - работать будет на ура, но для начинающего оно сильно сурово.
Стоит поставить LXDE в качестве графической среды рабочего стола, чтобы вначале полегче ориентироваться было. Дистрибутив, в принципе, не так важен, выбери что-нибудь популярное.
Мое мнение о подходящем дистрибутиве - OpenSUSE. Нормально русифицирован, стабилен, прост для начального освоения. (L)AMP ставится без проблем, для создания страничек quanta plus в помощь.
Товарищ выше писал уже про OpenSUSE - не заметил.

Comment: Ничего страшного, что я уже писал про OpenSuse. Рад, что есть единомышленники.
LAMP - Apache, MySQL, PHP я идентифицирую в этой аббревиатуре. А L что такое?

Comment: L - Linux.

Comment: Почитайте внимательнее. Человек спрашивает что будет работать на слабом железе.

Answer (score 1):

Командная строка есть везде, `lamp/xampp` - ставится легко везде, было бы желание учится и спрашивать, а теперь главное - ставить надо ту систему, в которой у тебя есть знакомые и у которых ты можешь спросить, если нету таковых то ставьте ту, в которой вам нравится и понятна поддержка.

Например, полазьте по инету и посмотрите на форумы и время отклика на новые темы, насколько много тем и насколько быстро на них отвечают.

Answer (score 1):

Настоящий и истинный Линукс - это SlackWare Linux. Самый старый дистрибутив, в котором сохранилась все первозданность этой операционной системы. Конечно, с ним не легко придется, но как говорится, "кто знает RedHat, тот знает только RedHat и не более, а кто знает SlachWare, тот действительно знает Линукс"

Comment: Попахивает фанатизмом :-)
Не то, чтобы Слака плоха... Но она какая-то архаичная. По тому же рейтингу http://distrowatch.com/ она на 13-м месте. А похожий по идеологии Arch на 7. Поэтому я бы последний и рекомендовал.

Comment: Вопрос был не в том что выбрать для изучения а что будет держатся на старом железе.

Answer (score 1):

Ставьте [Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/) настроите всё под себя, собирайте систему и пакеты на более мощном компьютере.

Answer (score 1):

Можете выбрать любой Linux-дистрибутив (Слаку и Генту для новичка не рекомендую) и поставить на него какую-нибудь лёгкую среду рабочего стола. В этом плане LXDE многие хвалят.

Answer (score -1):

Выкинуть этот хлам и поставить в виртуальную машину любой понравившийся дистрибутив.